# Optimising mongodb two phase commit queries

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have read the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) which suggests a two phase commit pattern for doing multi-document updates.

I created an example as below (using node js native drive).

```js
// produce collection

[{
  _id: 'p01',
  name: 'apple',
  qty: 10,
  transaction: [],
}, {
  _id: 'p02',
  name: 'banana'
  qty: 30,
  transaction: [],
}, {
  _id: 'p03',
  name: 'carrot',
  qty: 20,
  transaction: [],
}]

// transaction collection

[{
  _id: 't01',
  product: [{ _id: 'p01', qty: 2 }]
}]


// need to get more bananas for monkeys

db.collection('transactions')
  .insertOne({ // <- 1st query here
    _id: 't02',
    product: [{ _id: 'p02', qty: 5, status: 'initial' }]
  })
  .then(updateProduceQuantity({ _id: 'p02', qty: -5, transaction: 't02' })) // <- 2nd query here
  .then(completeTransaction({ _id: 't02' })) // <- 3rd query here
  .then(completeProduce({ _id: 'p02', transaction: 't02' })) // <- 4th query here
  .catch(function (e) {})


function updateProduceQuantity({ _id, qty, transaction }) {
  return function () {
    return db.collection('fruits')
      .updateOne({ _id }, { $inc: { qty }, { $push: transaction } })
  }
}

function completeTransaction({ _id }) {
  return function () {
    return db.collection('transactions')
      .updateOne({ _id }, { $set: { status: 'done' }})
  }
}

function completeProduce({ _id, transaction }) {
  return function () {
    return db.collection('fruits')
      .updateOne({ _id }, { $pull: transaction })
  }
}
```

If I understand this correctly, that at the application level, at least 4 queries are required.
My questions are:

1) Is this efficient as data has to be passed back and fro between the application and server (particularly if the mongo server is hosted elsewhere with high latency, or in situation where queries are more complex)?

2) If this is inefficient, is using [javascript in mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) a better option?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1- is the preferred approach in terms of software maintenance perspective. Placing the Javascript in the server and execute it would provide better performance and can be used if this whole process is developed for one time use in production environment. If it is a long time solution, definitely option 1 is the preferred option.